# display image in tcltk window with R... How?

Tags: image, r, package, tcl

Can anyone tell me how to dislpay an image in a tcltk window ?

I found **Img** package here : [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tkimg/files/tkimg/) (1.3 version)
but I can't install it manually because of missing 'DESCRIPTION' file.

How can I install it ?

-> How can I display image on a tcltk window (using Img package or not) ?

thank you

Config : Windows 7 64 bits, R 3.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a label for this:

```
w <- tktoplevel()
tcl("image","create","photo", "imageID", file="your_image.gif")
l <- ttklabel(w, image="imageID", compound="image")
tkpack(l)
```

This only supports a limited number of file formats though.

Comment: .gif ?
Does it work only for .gif file ?
I just need it to support png OR jpeg

Comment: For that you need to convert. Do you have a system utility like imagemagick?  That is easiest. Otherwise `Img` is a tcl package that can be installed. This old link might help: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2005-August/077811.html . The `tkrplot` package can also generate files for display from graphics.

Comment: ok, and which of those [**arguments**](http://127.0.0.1:31336/library/tkrplot/html/TkRplot.html) I use to load my pic ?

Comment: I convert my jpg file to a gif one, and [jverzani](http://stackoverflow.com/users/340844/jverzani)'s answer works great! :D.... now, the  problem is how to plot histogram on gif files.. thank you!