# R tcltk: error when trying to display a png file depending on the OS

Tags: r, tcl, png, tk-toolkit

This is an issue I am encountering for different pieces of codes I am writing in R. 
Basically, I would like to generate a window that displays a picture (a .png file). Following for instance guidances from [this](http://www.sciviews.org/recipes/tcltk/TclTk-image-display) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581954/is-there-a-way-to-convert-image-with-r-jpeg-to-gif-for-example), I come up with this kind of code:

```
library(tcltk)
tmpFile <- tempfile(fileext = ".png")
download.file("https://www.r-project.org/logo/Rlogo.png", tmpFile)

tcl("image","create","photo", "imageLogo", file=tmpFile)
win1 <- tktoplevel()
tkpack(ttklabel(win1, image="imageLogo", compound="image"))
```

This works fine under Mac OS, but not on Linux nor on Windows, where I am displayed such an error message:

> [tcl] couldn't recognize data in image file

I can find some workarounds when I want to display graphs, using for instance packages `tkrplot` or `igraph`. Nonetheless, I would be really eager to understand why I got such errors when running my scripts on Linux or Windows, whereas it works just fine on Mac OS.

Apologies in case this issue is obvious, but I haven't found anything about potential differences with the `tcltk` package depending on the OS.

Comment: What versions of the Tk library are involved? This matters since PNG support wasn't natively in Tk until 8.6. (I wrote quite a bit of that code…)

Comment: On my Windows version of R 3.3.1 I have tcl 8.5 and on Ubuntu under R 3.3.1 I have tcl 8.6 so that seems to be the difference as @Donal Fellows thought.  The code in the question did work for me on Windows with a gif file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tk's native support for PNG was added in 8.6. Prior to that, you need to have the [tkimg extension](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tkimg/) loaded *into Tk* to add the image format handler required. If your installation of Tcl/Tk that R is using is set up right, you can probably make it work with:

```
tclRequire("Img")
```

once you've initialised things sufficiently. Yes, the name used internally is “`Img`” for historical reasons, but that's just impossible to search for! (This is the key thing [in this mailing list message from way back](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2005-August/077811.html).)

However, upgrading the versions of Tcl and Tk to 8.6 is likely to be a better move.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, @donal-fellows! I take from your answer and also comments by you and @g-grothendieck that: 1) I have to use an up-to-date version of R (I do not have the feeling that Tcl/Tk is installed as an independant library on my Windows distribution, but I may be wrong) 2) I'd better use natively supported formats such as gif (following [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580818/display-image-in-tcltk-window-with-r-how?rq=1) BTW). 3) In the end, I can also use the package "Img" (but I need to figure out first how R is interacting with Tk)

Comment: On Windows tcl is bundled with R.  From within R it is in the `R.home("Tcl")` tree.   R 3.4, the devel version of R, does currently provide tcl 8.6 under Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Finally and a bit lately, I would like to close this issue and sum up the different suggestions that were kindly made in response of my question:

- R comes along with Tcl 8.5, even with the latest version 3.3.2, which means that there is no way for embedding a PNG file with the usual command into a window created thanks to Tcl/Tk. For some reasons it is working on Mac OS, but do not expect this to work easily on other OSs.
- In order to display pictures, graphs, etc. in a window generated by Tcl/Tk in R, better look for either using the GIF support (when possible) or trying alternative solutions (see the question for possible alternative options).
- In case one really wants to display PNG files, the solution consists of installing Tcl 8.5 (for instance ActiveTcl) along with the extension Img. In order to use the Tcl/Tk package that you've just installed on your computer, you can refer to the [R FAQ for Windows](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#Package-TclTk-does-not-work_002e) for instance (as stated in the FAQ, you need to install Tcl 8.5 - I tried with Tcl 8.6, thereby hoping to solve my issue, but it didn't work). Basically, you need to set up an environment variable (`MY_TCLTK`) and put the path where the package Tcl/Tk is installed. Needless to be said, Tcl/Tk is commonly used in R in order to implement GUIs; if you have to go through very complex procedures to set up the system, the package definitely loses its advantages.
- Finally, since Tcl 8.6 should be available soon or later with R (already implemented in the devel version), this issue will be *de facto* outdated.